# SharePoint and Silverlight web part versions

Tags: 2007, silverlight, web-part

We have a customer with several SharePoint installations, both 2007 and 2010.

We are looking at developing Silverlight web parts.

Is there a depenancy that you must use Silverlight 3 for SP 2007 and Silverlight 4 for SP 2010? Or is it possible to deploy Silverlight 4 to SP 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight 4 and SP2007 work just fine together. SharePoint 2007 was released well before even Silverlight 3 was out.